# $\lim_{x \to 0} (e^x - 1)/x^8$ .

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

I want to know how to solve this limit problem with Maclaurin's series expansion of only $e^x$ in the neighborhood of $x=0$.

Comment: Both methods work. Why do you think they don’t work?

Comment: @RedGiant L'Hôpital's rule doesn't work here because none of the limits exist.

Comment: @BenjaminWang L'Hopital's rule fails here.

Comment: What if i only expand e^x as 1+( x^1)1! + (X^2)/2! And so on

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly apply l'Hôpital here, provided you distinguish between the limits from the right and from the left. Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x}{8x^7}=\infty
$$
you can certainly conclude that
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x-1}{x^8}=\infty
$$
Similarly
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^x}{8x^7}=-\infty
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^x-1}{x^8}=-\infty
$$
Hence the two-sided limit doesn't exist.

What about Taylor (or Maclaurin, if you prefer to call it this way)? The Taylor expansion is $e^x-1=x+o(x)$ so you have, from the right,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x-1}{x^8}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+o(x)}{x^8}=\infty
$$
(you get $\infty$ because you know that the function is positive in a right punctured neighborhood of $0$). Similarly for the limit from the left and you get the same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

The limit does not exist. $(e^x-1)/x^8$ approaches infinity as $x$ approaches $0$ from the positive end, but $(e^x-1)/x^8$ approaches negative infinity as $x$ approaches $0$ from the negative end. L'Hôpital's rule states that if $f(x) \to 0$ and $g(x) \to 0$ as $x$ approaches $a$, then
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$
*provided that*
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$
exists. In this case, that limit does not exist, and so L'Hôpital is not applicable.

Comment: You can apply l'Hôpital. Just don't do it too naively.

Comment: @egreg My point was about evaluating the two-sided limit (which does not exist), but of course you are right that L'Hôpital is applicable for the one-sided limits. So I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{e^x-1}{x^8}=\frac{1+x+o(x^2)-1}{x^8}.$$

You can conclude.